# Issue in webpy db select query

Tags: python, mysql, database, web.py

In webpy db module I have a query:

```
 db().query("select * from table where column in ($ERROR_LIST)",
    vars=dict(ERROR_LIST=ERROR_LIST)).list()
```

There is no issue with this query if the `ERROR_LIST` is just a variable. But my requirement is that the `ERROR_LIST` must be list of error values. Is there a way to handle list in webpy DB module or is there any other way to do the job?

Comment: Please don't use bold for code highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a variable `error_list`that holds a list of the values, let webpy convert everything for you and don't add the () arround the variable either:

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN $ERROR_LIST", vars(dict(ERROR_LIST,error_list)))
```

Since I believe `reparam` uses the same methods, this seems to work (including adding parenthesis for you):

```
>>> error_list = ['a','b','c']
>>> reparam("s IN $ERROR_LIST", dict(ERROR_LIST=error_list))
<sql: "s IN ('a', 'b', 'c')">
```